# How to setup different permlalinks for posts and pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks, pages

I'd like to setup:

```
www.mydomain.com/a-page/
www.mydomain.com/blog/category_name/
www.mydomain.com/blog/category_name/post_name/
www.mydomain.com/custom_post/post_name/
```

How would I do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Options » Permalinks just add a base for post permastruct. Ex: `/blog/%postname%/`.

Make sure that your custom post types are registered with `'with_front'` => `false` in rewrite argument. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: "This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Please add more detail to the answer to avoid this issue-- for example, links to relevant Codex Pages.

Comment: lol. The answer contains all the details needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Short answers get flagged, whether they deserve it or not. It is an automated system, after all. I've seen toscho's get flagged and I'm sure some of mine have been flagged. Just add a bit more description and a link or two and it won't happen. It is also good to keep in mind that "the details needed to solve the problem" is relative to the person reading the answer. Not everyone understands as much as you. If they did they wouldn't be asking.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dan. This answered my question. Simplicity rules! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your WordPress dashboard, go to Settings / Permalinks. Click custom structure, and leave /%post-name%/. You can also edit the tag / category base in this section.

Comment: So far it is: /blog/%category%/%postname%/

Comment: that should be exactly what you're looking for. I usually delete the /%category%/ part ...but it looks like you want to keep it there for posts?

Comment: if you want to remove /blog/ for your pages - you'll need to move your WordPress installation to the root directory. Right now, it seems like you've got WordPress installed at www.yoursite.com/blog/ ...in which case you won't be able to remove the '/blog' section from your URLs. Make sense?

Comment: once you've done that, you can add '/blog' before the /%post-name%/ part in your permalink settings.